# 16.04 hanging on boot up 2016 Razer Blade

Tags: boot, 16.04, live-usb

I recently purchased a 2016 Razer Blade and want nothing more than to use Windows as little as possible. However when booting to Ubuntu live USB it hangs on this.

[image: Screenshot]

I've never run into this problem installing ubuntu on any other device. I saw many other Blade users were having issues with their machines, but none that were having the exact same issue.

Exact specifications: i7-6700HQ, GTX 970M (HD 530), 16GB DDR4, 512GB Samsung 950 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

https://xipherzero.com/ubuntu-16-04-razer-blade-2016/

The link above solves your problem. Instead of the three command lines, you can skip "nolapic" to make it work. Basically, you can modify the boot by adding the following two commands

`i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 nouveau.modeset=0`

Comment: Please add more information as gotten from that link in case the link changes or is broken.